# Selecting all faces on a plane on imported mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

I am working with an STL file that was generated outside of Blender and then imported. The mesh has a flat plane (the selected face in the photo is along that plane), but it is composed of many faces. My desire is to combine all the faces with the eventual goal of extruding it. In my screenshot I have started by selecting some of the faces manually and combining them.

I'm looking for a way to select all of the faces on the plane as it is quite tedious if I have to select each one manually.

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of mesh with face selected.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and select normal. This will select all faces with the same orientation.

**Option 2:** Press some number on the numpad to snap your view to a specific axis. That will show you all of the faces as if they were 2 dimensional, and you are looking at the from the side. Then you can press <kbd>Z</kbd> to change to wireframe mode. Next, press <kbd>B</kbd> (box select) and drag a box across all the vertices you want.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> and select *Co-planar*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This answer was precisely what I was looking for. They don't have to be long to be good.